# Array values to a string in loop

Tags: javascript

I have an object (key value pair) looks like this

[image]

I want to get a string of '[100000025]/[100000013]'

I can't use `var str = OBJ[0].PC + OBJ[1].PC` (which gives me '100000025100000013')
because I need the bracket structure.
The number of items can vary.

**Added >> Can it be done without using arrow function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use classic for in loop

```
let arr = [{PC:'1000'},{PC:'10000'}]
let arrOut = [];
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrOut.push('[' + arr[i].PC + ']'); 
}
```

now the arrOut is equal ["[1000]", "[10000]"] what we need is to convert it to a string and add '/' between items.

```
let str = arrOut.join('/');
console.log(str) // "[1000]/[10000]"
```

Comment: Great! this is what I've been wanting for! Thanks!

Comment: OP, please update and select the right answer for future developers to help with. thank you;

Answer (score 6):

```
 const string = array.map(({PC}) => `[${PC}]`).join('/')
```

You could map every string to the string wrapped in brackets, then join that by slashes.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer! Can it be done without using arrow function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map() and a join() to get that structure. - this is hte same solution as Puwka's = but without the template literal.

```js
var data = [
  {am: 1, ct: "", pc: "1000000025"},
  {am: 2, ct: "", pc: "1000000013"}
];

let newArr = data.map(item => "[" + item.pc +"]");

console.log(newArr.join("/")); // gives [1000000025]/[1000000013]
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need a string in the format of: xxxx/yyyyy from a complex object array.

```
const basedata = [...];
const result = basedata.map( item => `[${item.PC}]` ).join('/')
```

so i will explain it now.  The map function will return a new array with 1 entry per item.  I state that I want PC, but i added some flavor using ticks to inject it inbetween some brackets.  At this point it looks like:  `["[1000000025]","[100000013]"]` and then join will join the arrays on a slash, so it will turn into an array.

```
"[100000025]/[100000013]"
```

Now, this will expand based on the items in your basedata.  So if you have 3 items in your basedata array, it would return:

```
"[10000000025]/[100000013]/[10000888]"
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to divide the result then it will be better to change it into number and then just do the division.
Example

```
Number.parseInt("100000025")/Number.parseInt("100000013")
```

If you want to display it then better to use string interpolation
surround it with back tick
 `[${[0].PC}]/[${[1].PC}]`

Hope this is what are you looking for

Comment: I think OP wants the result to be the *string* `[100000025]/[100000013]` not, the mathematical operation`100000025 / 100000013` of dividing two numbers.